# Using multiprocessing pool of workers

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following code written to make my lazy second CPU core working. What the code does basically is first find the desired "sea" files in the directory hierarchy and later execute set of external scripts to process these binary "sea" files to produce 50 to 100 text and binary files in number. As the title of the question suggest in a paralleled fashion to increase the processing speed.

This question originates from the long discussion that we have been having on IPython users list titled as "[Cannot start ipcluster](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ipython.user/4765)". Starting with my experimentation on IPython's parallel processing functionalities.

The issue is I can't get this code running correctly. If the folders that contain "sea" files only houses "sea" files the script finishes its execution without fully performing external script runs. (Say I have 30-50 external scripts to run, but my multiprocessing enabled script exhaust only after executing the first script in these external script chain.) Interestingly, if I run this script on an already processed folder (which is "sea" files processed beforehand and output files are already in that folder) then it runs, but this time I get speed-ups at about 2.4 to 2.7X with respect to linear processing timings. It is not very expected since I only have a Core 2 Duo 2.5 Ghz CPU in my laptop. Although I have a CUDA powered GPU it has nothing to do with my current parallel computing struggle :)

What do you think might be source of this issue?

Thank you for all comments and suggestions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from multiprocessing import Pool
from subprocess import call
import os


def find_sea_files():

   file_list, path_list = [], []
   init = os.getcwd()

   for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
      dirs.sort()
      for file in files:
          if file.endswith('.sea'):
              file_list.append(file)
              os.chdir(root)
              path_list.append(os.getcwd())
              os.chdir(init)

   return file_list, path_list


def process_all(pf):
   os.chdir(pf[0])
   call(['postprocessing_saudi', pf[1]])


if __name__ == '__main__':
   pool = Pool(processes=2)              # start 2 worker processes
   files, paths = find_sea_files()
   pathfile = [[paths[i],files[i]] for i in range(len(files))]
   pool.map(process_all, pathfile)
```

Comment: Instead of calling the top external script, when I try to call the sub-script that is part of the postprocessing_saudi namely process_raw and execute I get a mysterious error:

Following is just a part of the error. As shown IDL execution is confused and cannot be obtained a right results.

[gsever@ccn partest]$ python proall3.py 
PID:  17722
PID:  17723
IDL Version 7.1 (linux x86 m32). (c) 2009, ITT Visual Information Solutions
IDL Version 7.1 (linux x86 m32). (c) 2009, ITT Visual Information Solutions
% Unable to obtain file status. Unit: 0, File: <stdin>
  Bad file descriptor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start with getting a better feeling for what is going on with the worker process.  The multiprocessing module comes with logging for its subprocesses if you need.  Since you have simplified the code to narrow down the problem, I would just debug with a few print statements, like so (or you can PrettyPrint the **pf** array):

```
def process_all(pf):
   print "PID: ", os.getpid()
   print "Script Dir: ", pf[0]
   print "Script: ", pf[1]
   os.chdir(pf[0])
   call(['postprocessing_saudi', pf[1]])


if __name__ == '__main__':
   pool = Pool(processes=2)
   files, paths = find_sea_files()
   pathfile = [[paths[i],files[i]] for i in range(len(files))]
   pool.map(process_all, pathfile, 1) # Ensure the chunk size is 1
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
```

The version of Python that I have accomplished this with 2.6.4.

Comment: The script visits the first directory and without starting the external processing process the script goes to the 2nd dir and try to process the first file from within there

[gsever@ccn partest]$ python proall3.py 
PID:  10723
Script Dir:  /home/gsever/Desktop/partest/20090317_131342/PostProcessing
Script:  09_03_17_13_13_42.sea
PID:  10724
Script Dir:  /home/gsever/Desktop/partest/20090318_075533/PostProcessing
Script:  09_03_18_07_55_33.sea
Processing the 09_03_18_07_55_33.sea file ....................... Processing the 09_03_17_13_13_42.sea file ....................... Done

Comment: Again the execution fails without even properly applying the external script chain on each sea files. I still think the issue is related to Python's multiprocessing module. I would be glad to hear some more comments to figure out the exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things I can think of:

1) Have you printed out the pathfiles? Are you sure that they are all properly generated?

a) I ask as your os.walk is a bit interesting; the dirs.sort() should be ok, but seems quite unncessarily.  os.chdir() in general shouldn't be used; the restoration **should** be alright, but in general you should just be appending root to init.

2) I've seen multiprocessing on python2.6 have problems spawning subporcesses from pools.  (I specifically had a script use multiprocessing to spawn subprocesses.  Those subprocesses then could not correctly use multiprocessing (the pool locked up)).  Try python2.5 w/ the mulitprocessing backport.

3) Try [picloud](http://www.picloud.com)'s cloud.mp module (which wraps multiprocessing, but handles pools a tad differently) and see if that works.

You would do

```
cloud.mp.join(cloud.mp.map(process_all, pathfile))
```

(Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of PiCloud)

Comment: 1) Yes, the paths are all correct. I test the same paths using IPython's parallel processing features and the main script goes through the folders and execute that mention scripts chain properly to fully post-process the sea files.

a) sort() is a work-around for my Fedora's file-system (ext4). Without it os.walk() visits the folders arbitrarily. 

2) I will take a look at 2.5. Right now I use 2.6.0

3) Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try, however I tend to not add external requirements for others to easily execute the script.